# Undefined method `assets' for ActiveRecord_Relation in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, instance-variables

I have a project model and asset model. a project can have many assets (uploaded by Carrier wave)

here is the project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, length: { maximum: 150 } ,uniqueness: true, presence: true
  has_many :assets
end
```

and here is the asset.rb

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader 
  belongs_to:project
end
```

In my index method in project_controller.rb ,I have the following instance variables:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
   def index
     @projects = Project.all
     @assets = @projects.assets.all
   end

  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:title,assets_attributes: [:id,:project_id,:attachment])
  end
end
```

and this is the view, index.html.erb

```
<% @assets.each do |p| %>
    <td><%= number_to_human_size(p.attachment.size) %></td> 
<% end %>
```

I have the error undefined method `assets' for Project::ActiveRecord_Relation :0x007fa60850dd08

Comment: Just do `@assets = Asset.all`, then go read the guides again and again: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: I definitely need to review it,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to call `assets` on `ActiveRecord::Relation` object instead of `Project` instance, this is why you get an error. To fix it, you could do:

```
@assets = Asset.all
```

or, to make sure you get only assets associated with project:

```
@assets = Asset.joins(:project)
```

Comment: Thanks, in an other method in my project controller I have `code`           @project = Project.find(params[:id]) , how can I define the assets ?

Comment: @user1876128 `Project.find` returns `Project` instance, so you can simply do `@project.assets` in this case.

Comment: I have a problem,for each project I now list all the assets not  the one associated to the project. I don't know how to add this constraint